# Limit ordered SQL query by primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, common-table-expression, window-functions

I have a query that orders the result by a specific none-unique column. Now I want to get the first `N` rows after a specific ID (the primary key).

I have a table similar to this:

| ID | Size |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 10 |
| 5 | 7 |

Now I order it by the Size (and ID to make the order stable) like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM FOO
ORDER BY Size ASC, ID ASC;
```

which results in:

| ID | Size |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 5 | 7 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 4 | 10 |

now I want the first 3 elements after the row where `ID == 2` so the result should be:

| ID | Size |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 |
| 5 | 7 |
| 1 | 8 |

I tried:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM foo
WHERE Size > (SELECT size FROM foo WHERE ID = 2)
ORDER BY Size ASC, ID ASC
LIMIT 3;
```

which results in:

| ID | Size |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 7 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 4 | 10 |

I also tried:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM foo
WHERE Size >= (SELECT size FROM foo WHERE ID = 2)
ORDER BY Size ASC, ID ASC
LIMIT 3;
```

which results in:

| ID | Size |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 7 |

I can't figure out how to get the expected result.

Comment: What if there are other IDs with the same Size as for ID=3?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel yeah I just realised that this would be an issue. Any idea on how to solve that if size is not unique?

Comment: That needs to be defined by you. One problem is that with Size not being unique, your ORDER BY clause is not deterministic and can return the rows with the same size in diferent order depending on engine, indexes or whatever.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel yeah sorry, I was thinking about that as well. In my project the size is actually a Date an I was thinking of migrating it to Datetime so the column would most likely be unique. Lets just assume the order is always the same.

Comment: You can extend the ORDER BY clause by appending a unique column. Eg. `ORDER BY Size ASC, ID ASC` if ID is unique and not null (or ideally PK). But then you still need to define **unambiguously**, which rows you want to select: Eg: "I want the next N rows after the row with ID=3 in the given order."

Comment: Ok thanks that already helped a lot, but I still have no clue how to get the next N rows after the one with ID=3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249067/discussion-between-jsiller-and-paul-spiegel).

Comment: First thing is to clearly define the problem including edge cases in the question post. Your sample data should ideally cover all edge cases. Once you did that, chances are good that someone will give you a solution.

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: @forpas it's 8.0.30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Size, ID) rn FROM foo)
SELECT ID, Size
FROM cte
WHERE rn > (SELECT rn FROM cte WHERE ID = 2)
ORDER BY rn LIMIT 3;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/qyqMw1ul).

Answer (score 2):

Use a `WHERE` clause with a subquery to only consider rows with a size greater than that of ID 3:

```
SELECT * 
FROM foo
WHERE size > (SELECT size FROM foo WHERE id = 3)
ORDER BY size ASC
LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: I realised that the Size is not unique so my problem is a different one now and my original approach wouldn't work either. E.g. if the row with ID=0 would have a size=3 as well it would not be considered in the query, but it needs to be. Is there anyway to solve that?
>= wouldn't work either because that would include the row with id 3, which I do not want.

Comment: That would simply be `WHERE size >= (...) AND id <> 3`.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL supports tuple comparison (row comparison). So that we can compare

```
(a, b) > (x, y)
```

which would be equivalent to

```
(a > x) OR (a = x and b > y)
```

Your query could be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM foo
WHERE (Size, ID) > (SELECT Size, ID FROM foo WHERE ID = 2)
ORDER BY Size ASC, ID ASC
LIMIT 3;
```

In the past MySQl didn't optimize row range comparisons well for an index use (not sure if they already fixed that). The workaround would be to use `(a > x) OR (a = x and b > y)` condition. The query would then be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM foo
WHERE Size > (SELECT Size FROM foo WHERE ID = 2)
   OR Size = (SELECT Size FROM foo WHERE ID = 2) AND ID > 2
ORDER BY Size ASC, ID ASC
LIMIT 3;
```

To avoid code duplication we can wrap the subquery into a derived table:

```
SELECT f.* 
FROM foo f
CROSS JOIN (SELECT Size, ID FROM foo WHERE ID = 2) x
WHERE ( (f.Size > x.Size) OR (f.Size = x.Size AND f.ID > x.ID) )
ORDER BY f.Size ASC, f.ID ASC
LIMIT 3;
```